# XSLT calling template inside of an HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

If someone would be kind enough to tell me why the following `<xsl:call-template name="Log">` won't work?

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextMessages>
  <Message>[Step]</Message>
  <Message>Step ID: 1</Message>
  <Message>Description</Message>
</TextMessages>
```

XSLT File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<html> 
   <body>
     <h2>My CD Collection &gt;</h2>
     <p>
       <xsl:call-template name="Log">
       </xsl:call-template>
     </p>
   </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name ="Log">
    <xsl:variable name="break">&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="TextMessages">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The wanted output:

```
My CD Collection >
[Step]<br/>
Step ID: 1<br/>
Description<br/>
```

The real problem has also parameters which I call with parameters, but not sure if that is the problem.

```
<p>
  <xsl:call-template name="Log">
    <xsl:with-param name="testId" select="@testId" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>
</p>

<xsl:template name ="Log">
    <xsl:param name="testId" />
    <xsl:variable name="break">&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="/t:TestRun/t:Results/t:UnitTestResult[@testId=$testId]/t:Output/t:TextMessages/t:Message">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What does not work? It works for me with xsltproc..

Comment: @user993553 I thought w3c was viable for a xsl test, but it fails there. The result is just written in a single line, without the template working.
However, tested with http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output and seems like it is working.
The bottom part is still not working in my code however.

Comment: Please show the expected result **as code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am guessing correctly, you want to change:

```
<xsl:template name ="Log">
    <xsl:variable name="break">&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="TextMessages">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template name="Log">
    <xsl:for-each select="TextMessages/Message">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
        <hr/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note:

1. You should never have to use a hack like `&lt;br/&gt;` to output HTML or XML valid markup;
2. I am not sure why you need to call a named template here, instead of simply including the `xsl:for-each` in the first template, or just applying templates to the `Message` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the 2nd Note, I deleted the whole template and directly added the `xsl:for-each` resulting in it working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line

```
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
```

to your XSLT file directly after the `<xsl:stylesheet... >` line will you the (partly desired) result of

```
My CD Collection >
[Step]
Step ID: 1
Description
```

With "partly" I do refer to the first line - which you explicitly want to be output by including `<h2>My CD Collection &gt;</h2>` in your XSLT -  but not mention in your output text.

Comment: I currently have `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>` and changing it to text would not help me.
P.S. Edited the wanted output, thanks for the note.

Comment: @Emir: Sorry, but I do not read that line in your XSLT code. Please add it to your question as well as your _full_ desired output.